# Conflict between MongoDB-engine and Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, django-rest-framework, django-mongodb-engine

My RESTful web service uses `djangorestframework` for RESTful web services, while I need to use `mongodbengine` to connect to MongoDB.

The problem is that they both have conflicting sets of requirements. While `djangorestframework` requires Django 1.7+, the `mongodbengine` is dependent on Django-nonrel 1.6.11 (forked version of Django).

The conflicting dependency is `django.apps`, which was added in Django 1.7. and it is required by `djangorestframework`.

How can I resolve the dependency problem, while still having both MongoDB and RESTful web services supported?

The full error:

```
No module named apps
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://www.somedomain.com/
Django Version: 1.6.11
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named apps
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/utils/model_meta.py in <module>, line 11
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/ubuntu/workspace/djangoserver',
 '/home/ubuntu/workspace/djangoserver',
 '/home/ubuntu/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
Server time:    Thu, 26 Nov 2015 13:44:30 +0000
```

Is caused by:

`from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets`